# Object Initialization With Several Arguments

Tags: python

Is there a better way to do this?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_var_1, my_var_2, my_var_3, my_var_4, my_var_5, my_var_6, my_var_7, my_var_8, my_var_9):
        self.my_var_1 = my_var_1
        self.my_var_2 = my_var_2
        self.my_var_3 = my_var_3
        self.my_var_4 = my_var_4
        self.my_var_5 = my_var_5
        self.my_var_6 = my_var_6
        self.my_var_7 = my_var_7
        self.my_var_8 = my_var_8
        self.my_var_9 = my_var_9
```

Assume that the variable names follow no pattern.

Comment: "Assume that the variable names follow no pattern." - it would have made sense to not *put* a big obvious pattern in the names, then.

Comment: The other option is to receive keyword args with **kwargs and loop through the dict to set instance attributes. You should force keyword args as you need the keywords to set the attribute name.

Comment: "The other" should read as "Another" actually. In Python there are almost always some other advanced ways to do something. You can receive a dict and update self.__dict__ with it, instead of iterating it to set the attributes, as a very simple example.

Comment: I think this is one of the few Python little annoyances, and probably dataclasses tried to address that. Note that dataclasses are still normal classes, they are not limited to hold data fields only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the purpose of the class is simply to hold a collection of related data (a "Plain old data class"), I'd use either a [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) (immutable), or a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) (mutable):

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class MyClass(NamedTuple):
    my_var_1: the_type
    my_var_2: the_type
    my_var_3: the_type
    my_var_4: the_type
    my_var_5: the_type
    my_var_6: the_type
    my_var_7: the_type
    my_var_8: the_type
    my_var_9: the_type
```

Or

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    my_var_1: the_type
    my_var_2: the_type
    # Ignoring other fields for brevity, but they'd be written the same as above
```

Where `the_type` is the type of each field. Unfortunately, the type hints are required by Python's syntax in this case. [Type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) are a good practice anyways though, as they help reduce errors that can be caught before the code is run. If you really don't want types, you can use the older `namedtuple` syntax:

```
from collections import namedtuple

MyClass = namedtuple("MyClass", ["my_var_1", "my_var_2", "my_var_3"])
obj = MyClass(1, 2, 3)
print(obj)
# Prints MyClass(my_var_1=1, my_var_2=2, my_var_3=3)
```

All of these options will generate that initializer for you, along with other features like nice `__str__`/`__repr__` methods. For example:

```
class MyClass(NamedTuple):
    my_var_1: int
    my_var_2: int
    my_var_3: int
    my_var_4: int
    my_var_5: int
    my_var_6: int
    my_var_7: int
    my_var_8: int
    my_var_9: int

obj = MyClass(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
print(obj)
# Prints MyClass(my_var_1=1, my_var_2=2, my_var_3=3, my_var_4=4, my_var_5=5, my_var_6=6, my_var_7=7, my_var_8=8, my_var_9=9)
```

*No manual initializer definition required.*

---

The main difference between the two types are `dataclass`es can be modified, while `NamedTuple`s cannot (much like normal tuples):

```
# obj from above
print(obj.my_var_6)  # Prints 6

obj.my_var_6 = 5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: I would suggest that you show an example of each of these classes being initialized, since that's the focus of the question.  What do the generated initializers look like?  As your answer stands now, I doesn't demonstrate that either alternative is a better way to initialize objects, which is what the question asked - Types weren't part of the original question, so your answer seems a bit "apples vs oranges" to me.

Comment: @Steve Yes. Unfortunately, I wrote this answer on a Swype keyboard on my phone in the app as I was getting off a bus. I'll try to improve it when I have access to a proper computer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, please do not risk your safety while answering SO questions (I think I never said something like this on SO). The answer is actually  accurate and to the point, but it does not explain the why, and for someone not knowing [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) might look like Steve says, because of type annotations.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to store arbitrary key/value pairs as though they were attributes of the object storing them, without having to define them explicitly, you can define a class that acts like a `dict`, but allows access to its keys/values via attribute references, like this:

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

class MyClass(AttrDict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Attributes built into your class
        self.predef = 'predefind'

    pass

# Define attributes at class creation time
mc = MyClass((('abc', '123'), ('foo', 'bar')))
print(mc.abc)
print(mc.foo)

# See that the class defined attribute is there
print(mc.predef)

# Change the value of an existing attribute
mc.abc = 'blah'
print(mc.abc)

# Create a new attribute
mc.xxx = 1111
print(mc.xxx)

from typing import NamedTuple

class MyClass(NamedTuple):
    my_var_1: int
    my_var_2: str
```

Result:

```
123
bar
predefined
blah
1111
```

If you want to enforce a particular set of arguments/attributes, then you'd need something more complex than this, or you'd want to go with one of the other alternatives.  But if you want to be able to use arbitrary attributes on an object with the minimum amount of setup coding (none), this is your answer.